# $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} \left(n\text{ mod }(n - i)\right) = \;$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

### The Question

Given a fixed $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, what is the value of the sum

$$f(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-2}~n \!\!\!\!\pmod{n - i}?$$

### My Work

So far, I have only been able to get a lower bound using triangular numbers. Let $a = \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor.$ Then we have the equality

$$\sum_{i=0}^{a} n \!\!\!\pmod{n-i} = \sum_{i=0}^{a} i = T_{a}$$

So $T_{a}$ is a very rough lower bound, as it is a truncation of half the sum.

Comment: OEIS entry: http://oeis.org/A004125

Comment: To a reasonably good approximation, $f(n) = 0.1775n^2-0.3142n$ (error about $\pm n$)

Answer (score 1):

Consider generating functions, odd numbers will give a contribution of $\frac{x^3}{1-x^2}$ , modulo 3 will give $\frac{x^4+2x^5}{1-x^3}$ and so on ... we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^{i+1}}{(1-x^{i})} \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} jx^{j-1}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now invert the sums & replace $\frac{1}{(1-x^i)}$ by the geometric sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{ik}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}  jx^{j-1}  \sum_{i=j+1}^{\infty} x^{ik}
\end{eqnarray*}
The inner sum is geometric ... we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}  jx^{j-1}  \frac{x^{(j+1)k}}{(1-x^{k})}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now perform the $j$ sum ... we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}   \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(1-x^{k})(1-x^{k+1})^2}
\end{eqnarray*}
So the value you want is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the sum above.